# Objective C take substring of string

Tags: objective-c

I have the following string :

```
[["hello","goodbye"]]
```

and I try to take "hello" and "goodbye" into two separates strings. I use:

```
NSArray *str = [mystring componentsSeparatedbyString:@"""];
```

so I cannot use `@"""` because `"` is a reserved character.

Answer (score 3):

You literal string is `[["hello","goodbye"]]` ?

Also you can use `"` if you do `\"` I do believe. Why not use the `,` and strip the `"`

Comment: Thanks, I didn´t know I can use \" to indicate that is a reserved word